# Phonegap 2.3.0 Xcode Error Compiling

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

when I create a phonegap-xcode project through console, and then compile it I have an error I can't deal with. I have looked for a solution in several forums, groups, blogs, etc but no one fits well. Actually, no one gives a quite solution.

The error I obtain is related to this import in the CordovaLib_Prefix.pch:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

I've got the error with XCODE 4.5, Phonegap 2.1.0, 2.2.0 and 2.3.0.

Thanks in advance,
DGM.-

Comment: phonegap provides template for Xcode. you can use that, instead of using console to create the application

Comment: I've tried right now, and got a similar error this time related to UIKIT import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your build target to iOS5.0 and remove armv6 from architecture list.
iOS4.x support has been dropped from Cordova/Phonegap 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with Phonegap 2.7 and what i did was i downloaded latest version of phonegap from [here](http://phonegap.com/download/#) rather than cordova and then follow the installation instructions from [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS). Worked for me, hope will work for you.